# How to Get Latest Updated TABLES in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I use Microsoft SQL Server to maintain the data which received from other software (Smartplant Instrumentation). I want to know the last table which was updated and inserted by the data from the other software.

I used this query, but I didn't get the correct updated tables:

```sql
SELECT
    SCHEMA_NAME(9),
    name AS table_name,
    create_date,
    modify_date
FROM
    sys.tables
WHERE
    modify_date > DATEADD(DAY, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY
    modify_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you ran only tracks changes to metadata, not the actual values.
You might want to to look at `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`, it could display the data changes in your tables:

```sql
select *
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('your-table-name')
```

But the best way is to add a modify date to the tables you're monitoring, or implement Change Tracking or similar.

Answer (score -2):

```
select top 10 name,modify_date 
from sys.tables 
where modify_date=(select max(modify_Date) from sys.tables)
```

this will return top to 10 tables recently updated tables

Comment: This is completely wrong. This will return top 10 tables that are all modified at the exact same time, which is the most recent change to any table.

Comment: This is a corruption of what the user already tried, and does not answer the question.  The user is attempting to determine when data in a table was modified.  You might vote to delete to prevent more down votes.